migrate edgeToEdge in jetpack compose from API 34 > API 35
I need to migrate to the newest version of android SDK/API.
The application starts and works fine on my personal android 14 device, but when i start it on a virtual android 15 device it doesn't paint system bottom navigation bar in my in-app navBar.
For example
Android 14
Android 15 VM (dark theme doesn't matter)
I use build-in navBar, there is my code:
CollegeSTheme {
                EdgeToEdgeConfig(
                    this,
                    bottomBarColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface
                )

                val navController = rememberNavController()

                Scaffold(
                    Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .navigationBarsPadding(),
                    bottomBar = {
                        BottomNavigationBar(navController = navController)
                    },
                    content = { padding ->
... useful part ends here


EdgeToEdgeConfig composable:
@Composable
fun EdgeToEdgeConfig(
    activity: ComponentActivity,
    statusBarColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background,
    bottomBarColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background,
) {
    val isDarkMode = isSystemInDarkTheme()

    val statusBar = statusBarColor.hashCode()
    val bottomBar = bottomBarColor.hashCode()

    DisposableEffect(isDarkMode) {
        activity.enableEdgeToEdge(
            statusBarStyle = if (!isDarkMode) {
                SystemBarStyle.light(
                    statusBar,
                    statusBar
                )
            } else {
                SystemBarStyle.dark(
                    statusBar
                )
            },

            navigationBarStyle = if (!isDarkMode) {
                SystemBarStyle.light(
                    bottomBar,
                    bottomBar
                )
            } else {
                SystemBarStyle.dark(
                    bottomBar
                )
            }
        )

        onDispose { }
    }
}

i have tried to shuffle EdgeToEdge config around and use Transparent color in the edge to edge method.

Do you see your logic being triggered on the emulated device? Meaning, did you debug it?

yeah, i have tried to change some colors and its responding on my android 14, and still doesn't work on 15.
and DisposableEffect is triggered in my EdgeToEdge on the Emulated device

Why do you use navigationBarsPadding() for the Scaffold? Have you tried removing it?

@tyg Thank you:) I didn't notice it, although i spent like hours debugging it. My final solution was wrapping all my content in box, and moving navigationBarsPadding() in its modifier/
